# Angular unit testing that a mutationObserver calls a function inside a directive

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, mutation-observers

So I am building a focustrap Directive in Angular, to use in for example modals/popups, where the focus will keep looping over the focussable elements in the popup. It uses a mutationObserver to keep track of for example changes in disabled property in childs and angular button components.
I am now getting stuck in unit testing the mutationObserver

Some of the used code I stripped because those parts are not important for this issue. Just know that at some point the disabled property can change in buttons
// focus-trap.directive.ts

```
 constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.init();
    this.listenForDisabledChanges(this.el.nativeElement);
  }

init() { // finds button elements without the disabled attribute } 

// The focustrap needs to know whenever a disabled attribute is placed i.e. in app-button component // after initializing
  listenForDisabledChanges(element: HTMLElement) {
    this.mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(
      (mutationList: MutationRecord[]) => {
        for (const mutation of mutationList) {
          if (
            mutation.type === 'attributes' &&
            mutation.attributeName === 'disabled'
          ) {
            this.init();
          }
        }
      }
    );

    // Start observing the target node for configured mutations
    this.mutationObserver.observe(element, {
      attributes: true,
      childList: true,
      subtree: true,
    });
  }
```

This is one of the unit tests I tried out, but it doesn't call the init function at the time of the unit test. I think it is a timing/waiting for the right moment kind of issue.

```
    it('should initialize again after a button changed disabled attribute', fakeAsync(() => {
      spyOn(directive, 'init');
      const enabledButton = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(
        'button:not([disabled])'
      );
      enabledButton.disabled = true;

      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(directive.init).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    }));
```

The unit test uses a testComponent that contains  that have a Input() for disabled attribute on the button

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-component',
  template: `<app-popup title="titel" content="content">
    <app-button [disabledButton]="true">Disabled Button</app-button>
    <app-button>BUTTON2</app-button>

    <app-button>BUTTON3</app-button>
  </app-popup>`,
})
class TestComponent {}
```